# Custom dojo on click error in IE

Tags: php, javascript, dojo

I have a custom dojo widget . When i click on the widget i get a javascript error as follow

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'set' 
focus.xd.js, line 8 character 6087
```

I removed all the events and i can assure you there is no events that are firing that i know of. 
The issue is only with IE 7. All other browsers work fine.

I have no clue why focus.xd.js is getting involved. i checked out the line 8 character 6087 in that file and this is the line that is getting executed

```
_29.set("focused",true);
```

_29 turns out to be an integer 1001 which is the id of my custom widget. I guess it is trying to access the id instead of the widget itself. What is a workaround for this??